# Как посчитать трафик поминутно Mikrotik?

Tags: роутер, аналитика, mikrotik

Между офисами настроен VPN канал с помощью маршрутизатор Mikrotik. Недавно столкнулись с проблемой нехватки пропускной способности канала. Провайдер не может дать больше 10 мегабит скорости. Запросили оценку прокладки выделенной линии между офисами у сторонней компании. У нас попросили поминутную статистику трафика и скорости на текущем канале, для оценки необходимой пропускной способности.

Как посчитать трафик поминутно Mikrotik?
Пишется ли подобная информация по умолчанию или нужно настраивать?
Где можно узнать/прочесть/спросить про подобные операции с Mikrotik?

Answer (score 1):

Tools-Graphing в настройках. 
Потом посмотреть можно в веб-интерфейсе http://192.168.0.1/graphs/
Подробно почитать можете http://www.technotrade.com.ua/Articles/mikrotik_graphing.php

PS: Но вообще требование о поминутной статистике очень странное. Ещё были бы понятны требования о максимально необходимых скоростях, но графики это странно.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.